# Initialise dependency at runtime

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

My app has three components, each with its own scope:

1. Singleton - Used for the lifecycle of the entire application
2. Activity - Used for the lifecycle of an Activity
3. User - Used while a user is logged into our server

Some of my activities have dependencies within the User component. However some of my activities exist when the user is not logged in and so must exist when the User component has not been created.

If my thinking is correct the best way to do this would be to define an extra component, giving me:

1. Singleton
2. LoggedOutActivity - For Activities that exist when a user is logged out
3. User
4. LoggedInActivity - For Activities that exist only when a user is logged in

Thus meaning that my LoggedOutActivities have no dependencies from the User component, and the LoggedInActivities can now have a dependency on the User component.

Creating this extra component and thus separating my Activities obviously adds some complication to the code, so before I proceed I want to clarify that this sounds like the right approach. Or is there a better approach that would allow me to tie all my Activities together within a single scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all just depends on what you want to do—and how.

First, your approach seems okay to me. If you have different dependencies, you will need different components. This is what components are for and this is how you should use them.

I, personally, most often have one component for every activity. I can then make this component depend on whatever other component it needs. I don't try reusing the *same* component for all of my activities.

If you want to reuse code, you probably want to reuse *modules*. If you always provide the same things from your activity (`Context`, `FragmentManager`, etc) just create a dedicated module to provide those. You then can create multiple components that all use the same module to help provide activity scoped dependencies—one for each activity, or one dependent on the user, the other on the app component as you described.